# Amen on a bracha levatala/sheino tzricha

Tags: blessing, amen

May a person respond amen to a bracha levatala or a bracha sheino tzaroch as the words of the bracha in and of themselves are true or is this improper?

Answer (score 4):

Shulchan Arukh [OC 215:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%93):

> כל המברך ברכה שאינה צריכה הרי זה נושא שם שמים לשוא, והרי הוא כנשבע לשוא ואסור לענות אחריו אמן:‏
> Anyone who blesses a blessing that isn't necessary has taken God's name in vain, and it is as if he swore in vain, and it is forbidden to answer *amen* to after it. (my translation)